# Are there health issues with gaining 24 pounds in one year if otherwise healthy?

Tags: body-weight

Got a check-up today at the doctor's office and the digital scale really scared me: 184 pounds, compared with my normal 160 from a year ago.  I am a 5'9" tall male.  My doctor oddly didn't mention anything to me - no words of caution, nothing.  Just gave me my blood pressure, weight, height, and answered some questions.

Is this kind of gain a health issue of its own, or only if I had other symptoms?

Comment: Voting to close because this is 1) a request for personal medical advice and 2) an opinion poll.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I would be worried because at 5'9 an 160lb, you were at a normal BMI of 23.6.

At 5'9 and 184lb you are overweight with a BMI of 27.2

The calculator I used was: https://www.nhlbi.nih.gov/health/educational/lose_wt/BMI/bmicalc.htm

The question now is: **Why**?

Your doctor may not be to concerned and this can fall under several reasons such as: Did not read your history chart, did not have enough history with you, or just feel compelled.

This means you need to take it into your own hands. Have you had any different patterns or daily habits from last year?

Has your diet change?

What is your daily routine?

Do you incorporate healthy habits such as gym, avoiding unhealthy foods, skipping meals or such?

If you are not sure, I suggest starting a journal recording daily events such as: When you wake up, what you eat, what is the dosage/weight/serving, where you dine at (if you eat out), when you go to sleep, any medications taken, etc.

After a week you should have enough data to pour through to see some observations that may be linked to the weight gain.

This is assuming the weight gain is from lifestyle and diet intake.

Comment: Welcome to Health! Please remove the tumor bit, there's no need to worry the OP with claims without references. This actually brings me to the second point: A good answer on Health.SE is expected to have references to support it.